# Como fazer um select dinêmico de marca e modelo de veículos só com html css e javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, banco-de-dados, projeto-de-software

Tenho que entregar o projeto na faculdade e uma das opções foi comércio de veículo, pensei em uma aplicação que pudesse escolher a marca, e o modelo aparecesse de acordo com a marca escolhida, com select dinâmico e se pudesse aparecesse o preço dos carros eu só sei o básico de html, css e javascript, não sei como usar banco de dados, quem puder me ajudar, com um código base ou uma explicação bem leiga para mim entender, eu agradeço muito

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Comment: Sua pergunta parece ter alguns problemas e sua experiência aqui no Stack Overflow em Português poderá não ser a melhor por causa disso. Queremos que você se dê bem aqui e consiga o que quer, mas para isso precisamos que você faça a sua parte. Veja algumas orientações que vão te ajudar: [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045) ([versão curta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8089/101)).

Comment: *"Tenho que entregar o projeto na faculdade...só sei o básico de html, css e javascript, não sei como usar banco de dados..."*.,  espero que sua faculdade não seja um curso de TI pois pelo que me lembro o projeto é entregue ao finalizar do curso.

Answer (score 0):

Caso seja algo simples e de fácil realização, não há necessidade para complicações. Utilize a praticidade, exemplo:

- Desenvolva seu index.html
- Desenvolva seu js.js

Posteriormente, inclua o javascript (js.js) ao index.html, especificamente, no elemento body.
**Importante:** Você pode optar por colocar o javascript diretamente utilizando o script tag. Mas, não é uma boa prática.

Feito isso, colete as informações e dê as opções. Para mostrar as opções no browser, utilize o método recorrente do Window, "alert". Já para coletar as informações do item escrito pelo usuário, o "prompt".

Assim, você poderá fazer:

```js
const informacoesPrevias = alert("Você podera escolher apenas um dos veiculos a seguir: [ Listar veículos ]");

const veiculo = prompt("Qual o veiculo deseja coletar informacoes?");

const veiculoDigitado = veiculo;

if (veiculoDigitado === "[ Nome do Veiculo ]" ) {
    document.write("<h1>Informações do [Veiculo] </h1>");
    document.write("<img src='[ Imagem do Veiculo ] ' alt='[Nome do Veiculo]'>");
    document.write("<p> Liste aqui, informações recorrentes ao Veiculo </p>");
} 

// Continue com as demais condiçoes e percorra o proposito da atividade.
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-BR">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Comércio de Veículo</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script src="js/js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```